# The down arrow acts like a back button in the browser

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, troubleshooting

A friend has an Acer Laptop running Windows 7.  When she presses the down arrow while in a browser (both IE and FF) it acts like the back button.  I checked sticky keys and they are not on.  She said that it started around the time that she installed a multidesktop system Yod.  But, she uninstalled it and the problem still was occurring.  One other weird thing is the fact that I worked on it a while and the problem was there, but then for no apparent reason it started working properly again.

PS she mentioned some other key problems, but I am not sure exactly what all they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a hardware issue. Try a USB keyboard first. Then boot into Ubuntu Live CD and see if the problem exists there. If it does you know it's a hardware issue, if not then it's a Windows/App issue.

If the latter boot into Windows' Safe Mode and/or start turning off processes that run on startup (msconfig etc). If the problem still persists perhaps somehow the keyboard settings in the registry have gone wrong? http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm